# siunitx option "symbol-or-fraction" not working in text mode with v3

Tags: siunitx

I have a problem with the `siunitx` package in its current version (v. 3.0.15). When displaying a unit using the `\per` command in text mode, the unit does not take on the attributes of the surrounding text (bold, italic, etc).

Is this an error on my part or a bug linked to this new version?

Version 3.0.15 also gives me the following error when compiling:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
$
l.21 ...a \qty{11000}{\kilo\metre\per\hour} bla bla}
                                                  \\
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

Here is my MWE, I added the result obtained by compiling with version 2 of the package:

```
%%%%%% VERSION 3.0.15 %%%%%%

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    mode                    = match,
    reset-text-family       = false,
    reset-text-series           = false,
    reset-text-shape        = false,
    propagate-math-font = true,
    reset-math-version      = false,
    per-mode                = symbol-or-fraction,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\textsf{Bla bla \qty{11000}{\kilo\metre} bla bla}&\textsf{Bla bla \qty{11000}{\kilo\metre\per\hour} bla bla}\\
\textit{Bla bla \qty{11000}{\kilo\metre} bla bla}&\textit{Bla bla \qty{11000}{\kilo\metre\per\hour} bla bla}\\
\textbf{Bla bla \qty{11000}{\kilo\metre} bla bla}&\textbf{Bla bla \qty{11000}{\kilo\metre\per\hour} bla bla}\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



%%%%%% VERSION 2 %%%%%%

%\documentclass{article}
%
%\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]
%
%\sisetup{
%   detect-all,
%   detect-inline-family    = math,
%   detect-inline-weight    = math,
%   detect-display-math = true,
%   per-mode                = symbol-or-fraction,
%}
%
%\begin{document}
%
%\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
%\hline
%\textsf{Bla bla \SI{11000}{\kilo\metre} bla bla}&\textsf{Bla bla \SI{11000}{\kilo\metre\per\hour} bla bla}\\
%\textit{Bla bla \SI{11000}{\kilo\metre} bla bla}&\textit{Bla bla \SI{11000}{\kilo\metre\per\hour} bla bla}\\
%\textbf{Bla bla \SI{11000}{\kilo\metre} bla bla}&\textbf{Bla bla \SI{11000}{\kilo\metre\per\hour} bla bla}\\\hline
%\end{tabular}
%
%\end{document}
```

With version 3.0.15:
[image: V3.0.15]

With version 2:
[image: V2]

Comment: The weird thing is, with your example I can recreate the problem only when having the commands within the `tabular` environment. In running text, they work absolutely fine.

Comment: OK, I see where the issue is: this is specific to `per-mode = symbol-or-fraction` in text mode

Comment: Logged as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/497, I'll look at a fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an oversight: internally, `symbol-or-fraction` uses `\mathchoice`, and that needs extra handling in the print routine in text mode. I have adjusted the code in this area, which you can add retrospectively for the present using

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__siunitx_print_text_replace:n #1
  {
    \group_begin:
    \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF {#1} \mathchoice
      { \__siunitx_print_text_replace:Nnnnn #1 }
      {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__siunitx_print_tmp_tl {#1}
        \__siunitx_print_text_replace:N \l__siunitx_print_tmp_tl
        \tl_use:N \l__siunitx_print_tmp_tl
      }
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__siunitx_print_text_replace:Nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    \ensuremath
      {
        \mathchoice
          { \__siunitx_print_print_replace_frac:n {#2} }
          { \__siunitx_print_print_replace_frac:n {#3} }
          { \__siunitx_print_print_replace_frac:n {#4} }
          { \__siunitx_print_print_replace_frac:n {#5} }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__siunitx_print_print_replace_frac:n #1
  {
    \exp_args:NnV \tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF {#1} \l_siunitx_unit_fraction_tl
      { \__siunitx_print_text_fraction:Nnn #1 }
      { \mbox { \__siunitx_print_text_replace:n {#1} } }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```